# Примитив GL_PATCHES. Что если из вершинного шейдера придет только одна вершина?

Tags: шейдеры, opengl

Здравствуйте, у меня теоретический вопрос по OpenGL 4.x.
В графическом конвейере `OpenGL 4.х` появился  этап `tesselation`, который идет сразу после `vertex shader`. В документации описано, что `tesselation control shader` работает с новым примитивом, который называется `GL_PATCHES`. Также там сказано, что `GL_PATCHES` формируется из вершин, которые пришли ему из `vertex shader`, и по умолчанию это количество `(GL_PATCH_VERTITCES) = 3`.
Вопрос. Допустим мы хотим отрисовать лишь одну точку (`GL_POINT`), она пройдет успешно обработку в `vertex shader` и перейдет в `tesseletion`, там она должна будет сформироваться в `GL_PATCHES`, чтобы продолжить обрабатываться, но `GL_PATCHES`, как я написал состоит из 3-х вершин (да, в самом `tesselation control shader` можно задать и кол-во в 1 вершину, но допустим у нас 3), соответственно, как сформируется наш `GL_PATCHES` (он возьмет одну вершину и будет работать с ней или будет ждать еще вершин)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя использовать GL_POINTS, это ошибка

> The error INVALID_OPERATION is generated by Begin (or vertex array
>     commands that implicitly call Begin) if the active program contains a
>     tessellation control or evaluation shader and the primitive mode is not
>     PATCHES.

Если патчу не хватит вершин (придёт 1, а не 3), он будет выброшен.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Патч будет выброшен - это означает, что не будет обработан и в итоге не отрисуется на экране?
Что означает?
>If tessellation is active
Это значит, если у меня в коде написаны мной tcs (tessellation control shader) и tes?

Comment: Да, патч не пойдёт в блок TCS (отметётся на этапе primitive assembly). 

Это означает, что включена шейдерная программа с TCS или TES шейдерами.